# Using two entities to create a form

Tags: symfony

I use one general form type class to create all forms in my application. From controllers I only pass some parameters to it so that it knows which fields to render. For example:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new CommonType($repository, $queryResultSet), new UsersEntity(),
        [
            'action'          => $this->generateUrl('user_edit'),
            'attr'            => ['class' => 'stdform'],
            'repository_name' => 'AcmeBundle:Users'
        ]);
```

And then `CommonType` class generates fields based on arrays from repository class.

---

However I need to add two entities now - the form has to contain fields from `user` and `shop` repositories/entities.

I thought about creating two forms here and connecting them, but I wouldn't be able to persist it to the database later.

How can I solve this problem?

I can't use form embedding because I have `CommonType` class here in my case.

Comment: You should really create a Form folder and have your form types. It's more clean and saves more time by calling the specific Type.

Comment: I do have it. But I still can't add another entity, that will generate fields based on specific repository class.

Comment: You should create them separately, and based on their relationship, add the subform to the base one. On your ORM mapping don't forget to add [cascade](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations): persist.